# Starting a side business whilst full time employed

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom, limited-liability-company, self-employment

I'm currently employed full-time in a regular job, and pay income tax at the higher rate. I'm looking at setting up a very small side business which may make around £500-£1000 at the moment. I'm basically selling a service and a recurring fee for support / maintenance, and will of course be paying tax on this.

Which is better for my needs, self-employed (my concerns are I wonder if this will affect my normal tax and P60 etc for my employer, or limited liability company (which comes with more overheads I believe).

In future, if I ever look at contracting full time (I work in IT), I would most likely use this business I'm creating for that as well.

I have little to no knowledge on the tax side of things, and would look at something like www.getcoconut.com to handle my invoices, tax and expenses.

Comment: Self employment is very simple.  Just fill out the self-employment pages in the self-assessment; there needn't be much more to it than a brief 1-line description of the business and 2 numbers; revenue and expenses, and you pay income tax on the difference (the profit).  It's completely separate from the employment pages you fill out for your regular job (although I seem to remember there's an option in the self-assessment to have your tax code updated, which would affect your PAYE).  A limited company would be far more complicated.